# Javascript is freezing the browser when running this code

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

I am trying to get the value of a text input and check if there is any links in it and then take those links and make them into  tags. But when I run this code, something is going wrong and it completely freezes the page. Basically, I want it to check for "http://" and if that exists, to keep on adding to the substr length until the end of the string/link. Is there a better way to do this?

```
// the id "post" could possibly say: "Hey, check this out! http://facebook.com"
// I'd like it to just get that link and that's all I need help with, just to get the      
// value of that entire string/link.
var x = document.getElementById("post");
var m = x.value.indexOf("http://");
var a = 0;
var q = m;

if (m != -1) {
    while (x.value.substr(q, 1) != " ") {
        var h = x.value.substr(m, a);
        q++;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's freezing because you've almost certainly got the potential for an infinite loop.

Comment: Also, your variables have terrible names. Code should be able to be looked at and roughly understood. This is not the case here.

Comment: The value of q never changes, so your loop condition never changes either, thus infinite loop.

Comment: Aren't you also missing a right brace "}"?

Comment: Indeed, your code is not complete.

Comment: This is just a snippet of the code causing the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course it is – there is an infinite loop.

You probably wanted to update the variable `q` in each iteration.

```
q = q + a;
```

or just `q += a;`

**Update:**

I see you changed the code a bit.

I get what you're trying to do. You're trying to get a URL from an input value.

Why don't you just use a simple `RegExp` instead of this unclear loop?

```
var match = x.value.match(/(?:^|\s)(http:\/\/\S+)/i);
var url = match ? match[1] : null;
```

Comment: I just tried that, I am trying the link http :// facebook.com, it doesn't seem to work correctly. You can try if you want: http://zach.muny.us/widgets/youtube It appears to only go one letter after http://